# Remove white space within string using awk or sed

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Given input file:

```
col1 as 'prod 1', col3 as 'prod 2', col9 as 'prod type 2'
```

Need to remove quote and replace blank space within quote by _ . Can we do it by awk or sed?

Desired output:

```
col1 as prod_1, col3 as prod_2, col9 as prod_type_2
```

Comment: A Perl solution: `perl -pe 's/'\''(.*?)'\''/$1=~y~ ~_~r/ge' input_file`

Answer (score 2):

A simple and portable `awk` solution:

```
awk -v RS="'" -v ORS='' 'NR%2==0{gsub(" ","_")}1'
```

which sets the record separator to a single quote and then replaces spaces in every second record (that is, the ones between single quotes).

That allows newline characters inside single quoted strings, and doesn't modify them. If you wanted to replace all whitespace, you could change the `gsub` invocation to use a simple regular expression:

```
awk -v RS="'" -v ORS='' 'NR%2==0{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"_")}1'
```

Eg:

```
$ awk -v RS="'" -v ORS='' 'NR%2==0{gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,"_")}1' <<<"
> col1 as 'prod 1', col3 as 'prod
> 2', col9 as 'prod type 2'
> "
col1 as prod_1, col3 as prod_2, col9 as prod_type_2
```

Comment: FWIW this one gets my vote for simplicity and portability.

Answer (score 1):

A `sed` solution:

If you can assume that the quoted strings do not have leading spaces, then this will do it:

```
sed ":a; s/\('[^,][^' \\t]*\)\s/\1_/; ta" my_file
```

If you need to also accommodate leading spaces in the strings, then this will do it:

```
sed -e "s/\s*$//" \
    -e ":a; s/\('[^,][^' \\t]*\)\s/\1_/; ta" \
    -e "s/' /'_/; ta" \
    my_file
```

The latter also has the side effect of trimming trailing whitespace; that could be avoided, if necessary, at the cost of a somewhat more complex command.

Both of these assume that there will be no whitespace between the closing `'` of a string and any subsequent comma (`,`).

Both of these have to deal with `sed`s substitution behavior: even when the `g` option is given to the `s` command, text that has been skipped or subbed once is not considered for further matching by the same `s` command.  That presents a problem for distinguishing whitespace inside a string from whitespace outside.  These `sed` commands work around that by using a label (`:a`) and conditional branch (`ta`, where `t` is the command and `a` is the target label) to re-run the whole substitution command from the beginning whenever a substitution is made.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk for multi-char `RS`, `RT`, and `\s`:

```
$ awk -v RS="'[^']+'" '{gsub(/\s/,"_",RT); ORS=RT}1' file
col1 as 'prod_1', col3 as 'prod_2', col9 as 'prod_type_2'
```

Given the new requirement to remove the enclosing quotes:

```
$ awk -v RS="'[^']+'" '{gsub(/\s/,"_",RT); gsub(/\047/,"",RT); ORS=RT}1' file
col1 as prod_1, col3 as prod_2, col9 as prod_type_2
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -v RS="'[^']+'" '{gsub(/\s/,"_",RT); ORS=substr(RT,2,length(RT)-2)}1' file
col1 as prod_1, col3 as prod_2, col9 as prod_type_2
```

Comment: Very nice, but the (edited) question requires the apostrophes to be removed.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a version to address the changed requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
echo "col1 as 'prod 1', col3 as 'prod 2', col9 as 'prod type 2'" | \
awk -F"'" 'BEGIN{OFS=""}{for(i=2;i<NF;i+=2)gsub(" ","_",$i)}1'
```

```
col1 as prod_1, col3 as prod_2, col9 as prod_type_2
```

**explanation:**

- `-F"'"` sets the ***f***ield separator to `'`, splitting each input line into *fields* separated by `'` (`$1="col1 as "`, `$2="prod 1"`, `$3=" col3 as "`, ...)
- `BEGIN{OFS=""}` sets the ***o***utput **f**ield **s**eparator to the empty string, effectively removing all `'`s.
- `for(i=2;i<NF;i+=2)` will iterate `i` over all even numbers up to the ***n***umber of **f**ields
- `gsub(" ","_",$i)` replaces all spaces in *field* `i` by `_`s.
- `1` will just print the (modified) line

---

***edit:*** One shortcoming(?)/feature of this approach is that it split by lines, so the single-quoted parts cannot span several lines. If this is a concern, splitting at `'`s into *records* instead of *fields* would be the solution (as demonstarted in [rici](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1566221/rici)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36603601/2451238)):

```
echo "col1 as 'prod 1', col3 as 'prod 2', col9 as 'prod type 2'" | \
awk -F\  -v RS="'" -v ORS='' -v OFS='_' '!(NR%2){$1=$1}1
```

```
col1 as prod_1, col3 as prod_2, col9 as prod_type_2
```

**explanation:**

- `-v RS="'"` sets the ***r***ecord **s**eparator to `'` splitting the input into *records* separated by `'`s (instead of lines)
- `-F\` sets the ***f***ield separator to , splitting each input *record* into *fields* separated by  (`$1="col1 as "`, `$2="prod 1"`, `$3=" col3 as "`, ...)
- `-v ORS=''` sets the ***o***utput **r**ecord **s**eparator to the empty string, effectively removing all `'`s
- `-v OFS='_'` sets the ***o***utput **f**ield **s**eparator to `_`, effectively replacing spaces by `_`s *in modified(**!**) lines*
- `!(NR%2)` is equivalent to `NR%2==0` and test if the current record (identified by the ***n***umber of **r**ecords) is an odd one (`%` is the modulo operator)
- `{$1=$1}` self-assigns the 1st *field*, marking the current record *modified* (even though it actually didn't change), effectively replacing all spaces by `_`s in odd records (*i.e.* text in between `'`s)
- `1` will just print each *record*

Comment: thanks for the answer...what if the input file contains any number of combination?

Comment: col1 as 'prod 1', col3 as 'prod 2', col9 as 'prod type 2', col6 as 'prod 9', col7 as 'prod 8', col8 as 'prod type 13'...

Comment: In this case you will get `col1 as prod_1, col3 as prod_2, col9 as prod_type_2, col6 as prod_9, col7 as prod_8, col8 as prod_type_13`, what's wrong about that?

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu-awk:

```
str="col1 as 'prod 1', col3 as 'prod 2', col9 as 'prod type 2'"

awk -v sq="'" -v re="'[^']*'" -v FPAT="'[^']*'|[^']*" '{
   for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i ~ re) {
      gsub(/[[:blank:]]/, "_", $i);
      gsub(sq, "", $i)
   }
} 1' OFS= <<< "$str"
```

**Output:**

```
col1 as prod_1, col3 as prod_2, col9 as prod_type_2
```